# Getting device info from Toshiba SmartTV

Tags: smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I have a little problem with development HTML5 app on Toshiba SmartTV platform.

Did anyone knows how to get device info from TV like Model, Firmware, MAC, IP? I tried to find some docs about it but, Toshiba is now one of the smartTV alliance and on there's website is only link to https://developers.smarttv-alliance.org/ what is great but smartTV allinace spec don't support getting this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a lot of device info is not available :( but some you can parse from user-agent

```
var getFirmware = function() {
    var match = String(navigator.userAgent).match(/Firmware\/([\d\.\-\_]+)/);
    if (match) {
        return match[1];
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};
```